# How does the iPhone 5 measure elevation?

Tags: iphone, accelerometer

I use an app called [MapMyRun](http://www.mapmyrun.com/) on the iPhone 5. In it is a report that shows elevation changes during the run.

[image: MapMyRun showing elevation]

Now to my knowledge, the iPhone5 has an [accelerometer](http://www.forbes.com/sites/timworstall/2013/10/18/the-mystery-of-the-apple-iphone-5s-accelerometer/) and [GPS+](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assisted_GPS).

The iPhone5 has no barometer or other way to measure elevation.

My question is - how does the iPhone5 measure elevation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Measurements are done using the GPS.

INFO: http://gpsinformation.net/main/altitude.htm

> GPS altitude measures the users' distance from the center of the SVs orbits. These measurements are referenced to geodetic altitude or ellipsoidal altitude in some GPS equipment.

Answer (score 0):

GPS calculations have to be done in three dimensions so your approximate elevation is always known while GPS is active.

However, accuracy is usually too poor to be useful so most services cross reference your location against online mapping data to get the elevation data for that point. This works a lot better most of the time but can lead to anomalies at bridges, tall buildings, cliffs, etc.